# How to backup shortcuts(hotkeys) in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know how to backup shortcuts(hotkeys) in notepad ++.
This will be really useful when one has to reinstall notepad using the backup files.

Please kindly show me how to do it,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed saved in the xml file "shortcuts.xml" in folder `%APPDATA%/Notepad++`

If you backup Notepad++, you might want to backup the following xml files:

- **settings.xml**: your settings
- **shortcuts.xml**: your shortcuts
- **userDefineLang.xml**: all your defined language (although it could be backed up directly from Notepad++ by using "Define your language" > "Save as...")

If you use NppExec, you might also want to consider backing up these files as well: `%APPDATA%/Notepad++/plugins/config/npes_saved.txt` and `NppExec.ini` (same folder).

Comment: You need to backup your APPDATA stuff if you want to transfer hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts are stored in the notepad++ installation directory in a file named `shortcuts.xml`.

On my Windows 7 system, the logged-in user does not affect this file.  My local copy is stored in:

```
C:\Users\paddy\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml
```

There are other settings in that folder too, so you can just back the whole thing up.

I am on a domain login, so if that folder doesn't help, just search your `AppData` folder for 
"notepad++".

Comment: the variable %APPDATA% can be used conveniently to back-up files instead of using hard coded full paths.